# Unable to get data from promise to view

Tags: angularjs, google-calendar-api

I was using google calendar api in angularjs and was trying to access the data in promise but i find the data is not accessible in view can you just check and let me know where i am going wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Google Cal Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello<span ng-bind="responsevalue"></span>
 </div>

 
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
 
 <script>
  angular.module('MyApp',[])
   .factory('gapi',function($window){
    return $window.gapi;
   })
   .controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','gapi','$q',myCtrl])
  
  function myCtrl($scope,gapi,$q){
   var vm = this;
    
   var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID HERE PLZ';
   var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
   console.log(gapi);
   data  = {
     'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
     'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
     'immediate': false
      };
   gapi.auth.authorize(data)
   .then(function(authResult){
    console.log(authResult);
    if(authResult && !authResult.error) return gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3')
   })
   .then(function(){
    return gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list()
   })
   .then(function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
    
    $scope.responsevalue = resp;
    console.log($scope.responsevalue);
   })
   
   
   
  }
 </script>
</body>
<html>
```

If i am doing anything wrong please let me know or if the code can be improved better way also do let me know.

Comment: are u getting the responsevalue in the console?

Comment: Yes i am getting data in console. but not to view @Jay

Comment: try to use $scope.$apply()

Comment: Thanks that worked... @Jay